# Hacer que strlen cuente el caracter nulo en C

Tags: c

Verán, quiero usar strlen para contar los caracteres de un mensaje (en un arreglo) pero strlen no cuenta los espacios en blanco, quisiera ayuda para saber como hago para que los cuente, estoy en lenguaje C.

```
printf("Ingresa tu mensaje");
scanf("%s",&mensaje[a]);    
printf("la longitud de \"%s\" es: %d",mensaje,strlen(mensaje));
```

Answer (score 2):

El carácter nulo (`\0`) no es lo mismo que el espacio ( ). La función `strlen` ya cuenta los espacios, el problema no está en el cálculo de longitud si no en la lectura de datos. Si usas `scanf` la lectura finalizará en el primer espacio, usa `fgets` en su lugar:

```
char bufer[200] = "";
fgets(buffer, 200, stdin);
```